# Does the MySQL Server join tables every time a PreparedStatement is ran?

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, prepared-statement

I am using a `PreparedStatement` with a join. Now my question is:

Does the `MySQL` Server join those two tables again every time, for example in a batch of 1000 of the same preparedStatements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, each time you execute the statement, the server will re-execute the query and have to redo the join.

What the server should NOT have to do is re-parse and re-plan the query.

Answer (score 2):

> Does the mysql Server join those two tables again everytime

Yes.

> in a batch of 1000 of the same preparedStatements

If you are running a batch of 1000 joins you are apparently doing something wrong.

Comment: thx.. I had to change the database structure a bit to avoid having to join the tables (initally this was for a insert statement)

Answer (score -1):

MySQL does have a query cache, so that in certain cases a cached result can be provided.  Here is the link

I would check here for more info.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html

A note included regarding prepared statements on the query cache says,

> Prepared statements that are issued using the binary protocol using mysql_stmt_prepare() and mysql_stmt_execute() (see Section 22.8.8, “C API Prepared Statements”), are subject to limitations on caching. Comparison with statements in the query cache is based on the text of the statement after expansion of ? parameter markers. The statement is compared only with other cached statements that were executed using the binary protocol. That is, for query cache purposes, prepared statements issued using the binary protocol are distinct from prepared statements issued using the text protocol (see Section 13.5, “SQL Syntax for Prepared Statements”).

I may be confused by you saying the "same" prepared statement.  If these prepared statements all resolve into different queries, then yes the joins will happen everytime.

If, however, any of these prepared statements resolve into the same query as one before, then the results might be cached (subject to limitation in docs), and no then the joins would not need to be redone.